# .NET MAUI ActivityIndicator not showing or disappearing depending on binding value

Tags: c#, maui, activity-indicator

I want to display an `ActivityIndicator` while doing some http calls.

In my view model I have a property

```cs
public bool ShowActivityIndicator { get; set; } = false;
```

A button command

```cs
public void UploadSurveyCommand()
{
    ShowActivityIndicator = !ShowActivityIndicator; //TODO: change
}
```

In the Page

```xml
<Grid Padding="10">
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activity"
                       IsVisible="{Binding ShowActivityIndicator}"
                       IsRunning="True"
                       Color="{StaticResource NavigationBarColor}" ZIndex="1000"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"/>
    <Button Text="{loc:Localize Upload}" 
            BackgroundColor="White" 
            TextColor="{StaticResource BtnColor}" 
            FontAttributes="Bold" 
            CornerRadius="30"
            WidthRequest="250"
            HeightRequest="50"
            Margin="0,15,0,0" 
            Command="{Binding UploadSurveyCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

When I press the button, and the `ShowActivityIndicator` value changes to `true` the ActivityIndicator is not shown.

Comment: Bind IsRunning, not IsVisible

Comment: No, it's not working

Comment: `ShowActivityIndicator` appears to have no `INotifyPropertyChanged` integration, so the view won't know when you change it.  As you're using the toolkit, use the [ObservableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) attribute.

Comment: Tried that too, now worked for me!

Comment: Please show the code where you make the HTTP calls. Does that happen inside a command?

Comment: In my test there wasn't a real HTTP request. That was just for example.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround:

In view model on the button event I added a `WeakReferenceMessenger`.

```
public async void UploadSurvey()
{
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send<ActivityIndicatorMessage>(new ActivityIndicatorMessage
          {
              IsActive = true
          });

    await Task.Delay(5000);

    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send<ActivityIndicatorMessage>(new ActivityIndicatorMessage
          {
              IsActive = false
          });
}
```

Where the message class has one property

```
public class ActivityIndicatorMessage
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

On the page code behind I register a `WeekReferenceMessenger` listener and registered it in the constructor.

```
private void SubScribeOnShowHideActivityIndicatorMessanger()
{
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ActivityIndicatorMessage>(this, (recepient, messaage) =>
        {
            
            activityIndicator.IsRunning = messaage.IsActive;
        });
}
```

Hope helps someone!

Comment: That seems awfully complicated. If you explain your problem better, there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: My problem was very simple. I press the button I the activity indicator appears, some process starts, when ends activity indicator disapears.
It is very simple, but ActivityIndicator's bindable attribute IsRunning was not detecting the binded value change, and because I need this to work, I made a workarround because I did not have a more time to put in this.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that this seems to be more complicated than it needs to be. Fixing the property to make it observable or using the command's built-in `IsRunning` property should suffice, like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Use RelayCommand's built-in `IsRunning` property

If you execute your HTTP requests inside an asynchronous method, let's just call it `MakeHttpRequestAsync()`, then you just need to change the method signature of your `[RelayCommand]` to `async Task` *(don't use `async void` for commands or anywhere else unless you must, e.g. event handlers)*:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
public async Task UploadSurveyAsync()
{
    await MakeHttpRequestAsync();
}
```

And then you can bind to the generated Command's `IsRunning` property:

```xml
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="activity"
                   IsVisible="{Binding UploadSurveyCommand.IsRunning}"
                   IsRunning="{Binding UploadSurveyCommand.IsRunning}" />
```

The RelayCommand's `IsRunning` property gets set automatically while it's executing.

There's no need for the `ShowActivityIndicator` property if you're only using it in a single place.

## Alternative: Make `ShowActivityIndicator` observable

However, if you want to use the `ShowActivityIndicator` property, then you'll need to make it observable.

Replace

```cs
public bool ShowActivityIndicator { get; set; }
```

with

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private bool _showActivityIndicator;
```

Then you can still bind to `ShowActivityIndicator`, it's up to you.

Comment: This was just an example. There wasn't any HTTP call in my example.

Comment: You mention that in your question, so it should be indicated somewhere in the code example.